next-auth 5.0.0-beta.18 signIn with credentials error=MissingCSRF
I have a minimal setup like explained in the docs of "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.18". When calling signIn() from the home page http://localhost:3000/,
./app/page.tsx

<form
      action={async () => {
        "use server";
        await signIn();
      }}
    >
      <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>

it redirects me to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F and correctly renders my login-page
./app/login/page.tsx

<form
  action={async (formData) => {
    "use server";
    await signIn("credentials", formData);
  }}
>
  <label>
    Email
    <input name="email" type="email" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Password
    <input name="password" type="password" />
  </label>
  <button>Sign In</button>
</form>

But when clicking the button I get the following error:
 ✓ Compiled /api/auth/[...nextauth] in 86ms (489 modules)
 ✓ Compiled /login in 196ms (732 modules)
 POST / 303 in 3328ms
[auth][error] MissingCSRF: CSRF token was missing during an action signin. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#missingcsrf
    at validateCSRF (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/oauth/csrf-token.js:45:11)
    at AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:71:100)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:34)
    at async /Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53446
    at async e_.execute (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:44747)
    at async e_.handle (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54700)
    at async doRender (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1377:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1587:40)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1924:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1962:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:920:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:272:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:816:17)
    at async /Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:336:24)
    at async invokeRender (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/Users/nickelpaulsen/programmieren/nextjs/auth-last-try/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:141:13)
 POST /api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F 302 in 10ms
 GET /login?error=MissingCSRF 200 in 108ms

When loading the login-page directly http://localhost:3000/login I everything seems to be working as expected. I already checked out everything I could find concerning this error but the remedies did not fix my error.
I have the example uploaded on Github: https://github.com/Nighel123/next-auth-error-MissingCSRF. My auth.ts looks like this:
./auth.ts

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
// Your own logic for dealing with plaintext password strings; be careful!
//import { saltAndHashPassword } from "@/utils/password";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        let user = { username: "lolli", email: "brolli" };

        // logic to salt and hash password
        //const pwHash = saltAndHashPassword(credentials.password);

        // logic to verify if user exists
        //user = await getUserFromDb(credentials.email, pwHash);

        if (!user) {
          // No user found, so this is their first attempt to login
          // meaning this is also the place you could do registration
          throw new Error("User not found.");
        }

        // return user object with the their profile data
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
});


The way that I got this working was inside your server component i.e login/page.tsx get the csrf token from the cookies using the below code
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const csrfToken = cookies().get("authjs.csrf-token")?.value ?? "";

Use this token and set it as part of your form
<input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value={csrfToken} />

Now every time you invoke the form action the token is sent along with the request. Auth.JS is happy internally and can verify the token.
Looking at the source code for the default Sign In page here - link I can see that they do something similar.

There ist also another solution: I figured out that if you are using the signIn from "next-auth/react" the error disappears.

if you have tried all the solutions and still struggling here is my custom signIn page (i'am  using next-auth version 5 beta and next version 14 ) :
"use client"
import { getProviders, signIn, getCsrfToken } from "next-auth/react"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import clsx from "clsx"

export default function Page() {
  const [providers, setProviders] = useState({})
  const [csrfToken, setCsrfToken] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    // Récupérer les fournisseurs d'authentification et le token CSRF
    async function loadProviders() {
      const authProviders = await getProviders()
      setProviders(authProviders)

      const csrf = await getCsrfToken()
      setCsrfToken(csrf)
    }
    loadProviders()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col lg:gap-4">
      {/* Formulaire de connexion par email et mot de passe */}
      <form
        className="flex flex-col bg-amber-50 p-16 rounded-lg gap-4 self-center"
        method="post"
        action="/api/auth/callback/credentials"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value={csrfToken} />
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:max-w-[75%]">
          <div className="flex flex-col">
            <label htmlFor="email">
              Email
              <input className="border shadow-md" name="email" id="email" />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col">
            <label htmlFor="password">
              Password
              <input
                className="border shadow-md"
                name="password"
                id="password"
                type="password"
              />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Se connecter"
          className="bg-red-500 cursor-pointer px-3 py-1 rounded-lg font-semibold text-white"
        />
      </form>

      {/* Formulaires de connexion pour les fournisseurs externes (Google, etc.) */}
      {providers &&
        Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
          <div key={provider.name} className="self-center">
            <button
              onClick={() => signIn(provider.id, { callbackUrl: "/profil" })}
              className={clsx("px-3 py-1 shadow-md", {
                "bg-green-300": provider.name == "Google",
              })}
            >
              <span>Connect with {provider.name}</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
 

and this is the auth.ts file :
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import type { Provider } from "next-auth/providers"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const providers: Provider[] = [
  // Credentials({
  //   credentials: { password: { label: "Password", type: "password" } },
  //   authorize(c) {
  //     if (c.password !== "password") return null
  //     return {
  //       id: "test",
  //       name: "Test User",
  //       email: "test@example.com",
  //     }
  //   },
  // }),
  Google({
    clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET,
  }),

]

export const providerMap = providers
  .map((provider) => {
    if (typeof provider === "function") {
      const providerData = provider()
      return { id: providerData.id, name: providerData.name }
    } else {
      return { id: provider.id, name: provider.name }
    }
  })
  .filter((provider) => provider.id !== "credentials")

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  // debug: true,
  providers,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, credentials }) {
      console.log("Profil Google:", profile)

      const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { email: user.email },
      })

      if (!existingUser) {
        console.log("Créer un nouvel utilisateur.")
        await prisma.user.create({
          data: {
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            image: user.image.replace("=s96-c", "=s400-c"),
          },
        })
      }

      return true
    },
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
    signOut: "/signout",
  },
})

now every thing will work ! ;)
